# CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement when deploying to a server

Tags: php, yii

I really don't know what causes this error.

```
    CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: CDbCommand failed to prepare the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY000]: 
    General error: 1 table 'YiiSession' already exists. The SQL statement executed was: 
    CREATE TABLE 'YiiSession' (
    "id" CHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY,
    "expire" integer,
    "data" BLOB
    )
```

Is it in the server or in yii..
but i guess it is in the yii part.
but what configurations did i miss?
i'm not really familiar with yii because im new to it.
any help please?
Thanks in advance

UPDATE: I check YiiSession in my database but it is not in there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the `runtime` folder.
Because runtime folder is used by the system for various tasks: session, logging etc.
It is also in the runtime folder that `YiiSession` table is created

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is still referencing this - the more complete answer is that Yii uses a SQLite3 database by default if you don't specify a connection string in your (CDbHttpSession) session config. This SQLite db is created in the runtime folder. (Which is why deleting the contents of the runtime folder works - you actually only need to delete the session-x.x.xx.db file.) If you want to use the same database you are using for your main connection, add:

```
 'connectionID'=>'db',
```

to your session config. It's also recommended for production use you set `autoCreateSessionTable` to false, which will also prevent the error - you just need to make sure you deploy the SQLite db or set up the proper table in your main db. see [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbHttpSession)

> By default, it will use an SQLite3 database named 'session-YiiVersion.db' under the application runtime directory. You can also specify connectionID so that it makes use of a DB application component to access database.